# Two Listboxes, one on top of another with one scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to have one scrollbar for two listboxes one placed on top of another, so that they scroll smoothly like they were one listbox.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just use one listbox?

Comment: the listboxes are placed on top of each other or..?

Comment: "on top of each other" in the Y or Z direction?

Comment: @jberger: yeah they are placed on top of each other.

Comment: @DanPuzey : the listboxes have different itemssources and itemtemplates

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like diff - when user scrolls one listbox, another scrolls too?

Comment: @EvAlex no. its just one scrollbar acrossthe two listboxes

Comment: @user1081106: are there the same number of items in each box?  That is, does one item in ListBoxA match exactly one item in ListBoxB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear to me, but I believe you can use something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="50">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="00 -Item0"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="00 -Item1"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="00 -Item2"/>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="01 -Item0"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="01 -Item1"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="01 -Item2"/>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: i tried it but somehow the scrollviewer scrollbar seems to be always disabled

Comment: @user1081106: the scrollbar will be disabled when there are no items to scroll. In my sample I've set the ScrollVieewr.Height specially to ensure that there are some items to scroll. How many items in your listboxes?

Comment: my mistake.. had to change the height of row definition of the grid to * (it was Auto earlier).. now it works fine.. thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can stack them above one another and make both of them autosize so that neither has a scrollbar.

Then place that contraption in a ScrollViewer.

I'm not 100% sure if the AutoSize/No Scrollbar is an option with the std ListBox, but you should be able to use an ItemsPanel instead.

Answer (score 0):

The below code example should help, if I understand your intention.

Note the Use of UIHelpers.FindVisualChild(...)  the code for this method can be found on-line by searching for "wpf FindVisualChild".
 Also the calculation of the vertical offset (e.NewValue * 10) seems to work well but the value of 10 was derived from a couple of tests. You may
 be able to calculate a better value or derive it in some better way.

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <ListBox Name="ListBox1"  Height="50" Width="100" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item0"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item1"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item2"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item3"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item4"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item5"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item6"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item7"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item8"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item9"/>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Name="ListBox2" Height="50" Width="100" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item0"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item1"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item2"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item3"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item4"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item5"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item6"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item7"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item8"/>
            <ListBoxItem  Content="Item9"/>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollBar Scroll="HandleScollChangeScrollBar" Height="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>

private void HandleScollChangeScrollBar(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer1 = UIHelpers.FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(ListBox2);
    scrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue * 10);

    ScrollViewer scrollViewer2 = UIHelpers.FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(ListBox1);
    scrollViewer2.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue * 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you to set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" in your top ListBox - I had this exact problem.